# Using ajax to send data to server

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc, dom

How do I send data from client side DOM object to server? Server is a Java spring mvc controller.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>AdditionsPage</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Order state</h1>

Customer name: test<br />
Customer Address: test<br />
Pizza size: 32<br /><br />

<b>Available additions:</b><br/>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>#</td>
        <td>Addition name</td>
        <td>Addition price</td>
        <td>-</td>
    </tr>


        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>tomato</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td><a id="row" value="1" href="/PizzaOrderApp/pizzaorder_add">Add</a></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>sausage</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td><a id="row" value="2" href="/PizzaOrderApp/pizzaorder_add">Add</a></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>onion</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td><a id="row" value="3" href="/PizzaOrderApp/pizzaorder_add">Add</a></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>fish</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td><a id="row" value="4" href="/PizzaOrderApp/pizzaorder_add">Add</a></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>green pepper</td>
            <td>40</td>
            <td><a id="row" value="5" href="/PizzaOrderApp/pizzaorder_add">Add</a></td>
        </tr>

</table>      
<br/>

<b>Chosen additions:</b><br/>

<table border="1">



</table>    

</body>
```

Above code is the source of loaded jsp in browser. Ajax call should take the value of the clicked row and send it to appcontext/addpage in a post request.
once call is done. How to get the sent value on server side?

Ajax code I intend to use:

```
$.ajax({  
    type:"POST",        
    url: "papp/addpage",
    data: $('#row').val(), 
    dataType: ?,//maybe jsonp
    timeout: 200000,

});
```

But I'd need assistance how to refer to the clicked link's row and if JSON is used, how to extract it on server side.

Comment: you have just added  href tags? where is an ajax code?

Comment: updated post with that. thanks

Comment: Provide javascript action events (e.g onclick="fun1()" ) and handle this ajax code in this js function

Comment: You will have troubles if you set the same ID for each <div> . I would set it as a class

Answer (score 1):

Hope below code will help you

```
$("a.row").on('click',function(){

    var value = $(this).attr('value'); 
    var href  = $(this).attr('href');

    var object = {}
    object["value"] = value;

       $.ajax({  
          type:"POST",        
          url: "papp/addpage",
          data: object, 
          dataType: json
          timeout: 200000,
      });  

    });
```